# what is the role of bins to plot a histogram?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a histogram. When I plot it with `bins=80` or `auto`, my code works correctly. But when I try to plot it with `bins=100`. It does not work with giving me this error:

```
"{!r} is not a valid estimator for `bins`".format(bin_name))
ValueError: '100' is not a valid estimator for `bins`
```

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x= [81.70900202536467, 81.69066539803865, 81.9634647036723, 81.6886583191991, 81.70063595809025, 81.71279936786232, 81.6846428541525]
plt.hist(x,bins='100')
plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```

What is the role of bins with histogram? How to choose the suitable bins value for my data?

Comment: Does it need to be an integer rather than a string?

Comment: Try using an `int`. Note however that you have very few unique values, so plotting a histogram of 100 bins doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: @yatu It is just an example to understand the role of  bins

Comment: Why for `bins='100'` did you switch to trying to use a string?

Comment: It seems quite well explained to me in the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

Comment: @dina Please don't edit your question to remove the cause of the exception you are asking about. If you do that, your question will make no sense.

Comment: @khelwood I don't edit it because it causes the exception. really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bins is the number of groups in that the data is going to aggregate for the count. For example, if you have the numbers 1,1,2,3,5,6,6 and you want 3 bins you get three columns(binds) in your histogram:

```
Column 1: [1,1,2] <=2 (value 3)
Column 2: 2<[3]<=3 (value 1)
Column 3: 3<[5,6,6]<=6 (value 3)
```

When you use a string in bins parameter the function expects one of this values: 'auto', 'sturges', 'fd', 'doane', 'scott', 'rice', 'sturges' or 'sqrt'. If you want 100 bins you should provide an int instead.

You can refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) to know more about histograms bins or [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) to know about histogram function.

Answer (score 3):

Set `bins=100` where the value is an integer, not a string as you have it. The bins are how many groups your data will be sorted into. In your example you only have 7 elements, so grouping those into 100 bins would make no sense. But if that's just a snippet of your data then you should be good to go!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x= [81.70900202536467, 81.69066539803865, 81.9634647036723, 81.6886583191991, 81.70063595809025, 81.71279936786232, 81.6846428541525]
plt.hist(x, bins=100)  # was bins='100' which is a string
plt.hist(x)
plt.show()
```